# Travese through all webs and intersect lists

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I want to traverse through all webs and child sites, to find lists with the same name and make intersection of them with child list priority  and show result in web part in repeater. Lists contain `Title`, `Name`, `Link` 
[image]

So far I have folowing:

```
 using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://niki/default.aspx"))
                {

                    SPWebCollection siteWebs = oSPsite.AllWebs;
                    foreach (SPWeb web in siteWebs)
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        try
                        {
                            SPList list = null;
                            try
                            {
                                list = web.Lists[ListName];
                            }
                            catch { }

                            if (list != null)
                            {

                                list.EnableModeration = true;
                                SPListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems(list.DefaultView);
                                repeater.DataSource = collection;
                                repeater.DataBind();
                                list.Update();
                            }
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            if (web != null)
                                web.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
```

The result shows only last iteration, and no intersection implemented. I have no idea how to add two SPListItemCollection, or is there another way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use List to store the data you needed, and you also can defined the data stucture by yourself.